# Redefining functions lin libC

Tags: c, libc

Assume the following simple `C` code:

`file1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* gets(char* i){
  return i;
}
```

which is redefining the libC native function `gets`.

This compiles fine with `gcc file1.c`.

My question is howcome the linker isn't complaining about `duplicate symbols` as this function is also defined in libC itself?

Comment: Note: `gets()` is not in the standard library of C11/C17.

Comment: @chux Linker warns with `warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used` when using it. I use C11.

Comment: Alex, be sure to try `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion file1.c`

Comment: the warning is a different matter and has to do with overflow protection

Comment: the warning about `gets()` is NOT about overflow protection but rather about the function `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed in the last two versions of the C programing language

Answer (score 1):

Because you can override functions from standard libraries in C, check [this](https://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/)

Comment: Overriding standard library functions is undefined behaviour, although it often (but not always) "works as expected". See [section 7.1.3 (Reserved Identifiers)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) of the C standard, particularly paragraph 2.

Answer (score 1):

add option **-whole-archive** in the link phase, as below:

```
gcc -c -ofile1.o file1.c
gcc -ofile1 -Wl,--whole-archive -lc file1.o -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

result:

```
file1.o: In function `gets':
file1.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `gets'
file1.o: In function `main':
file1.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `gets@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran into undefined behavior see `N1570 6.9(p5) External definition`:

> If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
>   expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or `_Alignof`
>   operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire
>   program there shall be exactly one external definition for the
>   identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.161)

As can be seen. The Standard allows 2 possibilities:

1. exactly one definition
2. no more than one definition.

This ***might*** depend on the linkage of `libc` which itself is system dependent. In case you link `libc` statically the linker will complain. In case of dynamic linking it have no reasong of complaining.

If you take a look at `objdump` you will find `plt` section like

```
898:   e8 b3 fe ff ff          callq  750 <gets@plt>
```

Anyway the behavior is undefined.